# How can I remove an account from Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I have a second-hand Xbox 360 with a huge amount of old accounts. How do I remove them? I do not have Xbox Live.

Comment: Wait, they didn't do that themselves?

Comment: no - they did not :-) but i'll be honest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just delete them from the drive. Go to System, and then choose Settings (when at the My Xbox channel, it's the far right item IIRC), then Storage, and select Memory Unit or Hard Drive (or whatever storage device the console is using). There should be list of the types of items stored there, one of which is Profiles. Select that, then delete each one.

Comment: This is more or less correct, except you got `Settings` and `System` back to front.

Answer (score 1):

System > Storage > Internal Hard drive or a different drive if you have it somewhere else > Profiles > The profile you want to delete > delete

Answer (score 0):

If you have xbox360, then...

1. Go to settings
2. Go to system
3. Go to storage
4. Memory unit
5. Go to profiles
6. Click on any accounts you don't want and hit delete

Comment: Not sure why this got a down vote. It is more correct than the accepted answer, except that my XBox360 says `Hard Drive` and not `Memory unit` in step 4.